# Как применить OrderBy в C++/CLI?

Tags: c#, c++-cli

Доброе утро, всем!! Есть класс на C#:

```
class HuffmanTree
{
    private List<Node> nodes = new List<Node>();
    public Node Root { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<char, int> Frequencies = new Dictionary<char, int>();

    public void Build(string source)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; i++)
        {
            if (!Frequencies.ContainsKey(source[i]))
            {
                Frequencies.Add(source[i], 0);
            }

            Frequencies[source[i]]++;
        }

        foreach (KeyValuePair<char, int> symbol in Frequencies)
        {
            nodes.Add(new Node() { Symbol = symbol.Key, Frequency = symbol.Value });
        }

        while (nodes.Count > 1)
        {
            List<Node> orderedNodes = nodes.OrderBy(node => node.Frequency).ToList<Node>();

            if (orderedNodes.Count >= 2)
            {
                // Take first two items
                List<Node> taken = orderedNodes.Take(2).ToList<Node>();

                // Create a parent node by combining the frequencies
                Node parent = new Node()
                {
                    Symbol = '*',
                    Frequency = taken[0].Frequency + taken[1].Frequency,
                    Left = taken[0],
                    Right = taken[1]
                };

                nodes.Remove(taken[0]);
                nodes.Remove(taken[1]);
                nodes.Add(parent);
            }

            this.Root = nodes.FirstOrDefault();

        }

    }

    public BitArray Encode(string source)
    {
        List<bool> encodedSource = new List<bool>();

        for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; i++)
        {
            List<bool> encodedSymbol = this.Root.Traverse(source[i], new List<bool>());
            encodedSource.AddRange(encodedSymbol);
        }

        BitArray bits = new BitArray(encodedSource.ToArray());

        return bits;
    }

    public string Decode(BitArray bits)
    {
        Node current = this.Root;
        string decoded = "";

        foreach (bool bit in bits)
        {
            if (bit)
            {
                if (current.Right != null)
                {
                    current = current.Right;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (current.Left != null)
                {
                    current = current.Left;
                }
            }

            if (IsLeaf(current))
            {
                decoded += current.Symbol;
                current = this.Root;
            }
        }

        return decoded;
    }

    public bool IsLeaf(Node node)
    {
        return (node.Left == null && node.Right == null);
    }
}
```

Я перевёл на C++/CLI и ошибка в OrderBy:

```
using namespace System;


private ref class HuffmanTree
{
    private:
        List<Node^> ^nodes = gcnew List<Node^>();
    public:
        property Node ^Root;
        Dictionary<Char, int> ^Frequencies = gcnew Dictionary<Char, int>();

        void Build(String ^source)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < source->Length; i++)
            {
                if (!Frequencies->ContainsKey(source[i]))
                {
                    Frequencies->Add(source[i], 0);
                }

                Frequencies[source[i]]++;
            }

            for each (KeyValuePair<Char, int> ^symbol in Frequencies)
            {
                Node ^tempVar = gcnew Node();
                tempVar->Symbol = symbol.Key;
                tempVar->Frequency = symbol.Value;
                nodes->Add(tempVar);
            }

            while (nodes->Count > 1)
            {
                List<Node^> ^orderedNodes = nodes->OrderBy(AnonymousMethod1)->ToList<Node^>();

                if (orderedNodes->Count >= 2)
                {
                    // Take first two items
                    List<Node^> ^taken = orderedNodes->Take(2)->ToList<Node^>();

                    // Create a parent node by combining the frequencies
                    Node ^parent = gcnew Node();
                    parent->Symbol = '*';
                    parent->Frequency = taken[0]->Frequency + taken[1]->Frequency;
                    parent->Left = taken[0];
                    parent->Right = taken[1];

                    nodes->Remove(taken[0]);
                    nodes->Remove(taken[1]);
                    nodes->Add(parent);
                }

                this->Root = nodes->FirstOrDefault();

            }

        }

    private:
        void AnonymousMethod1(Object ^node)
        {
            node->Frequency;
        }

    public:
        BitArray ^Encode(String ^source)
        {
            List<bool> ^encodedSource = gcnew List<bool>();

            for (int i = 0; i < source->Length; i++)
            {
                List<bool> ^encodedSymbol = this->Root->Traverse(source[i], gcnew List<bool>());
                encodedSource->AddRange(encodedSymbol);
            }

            BitArray ^bits = gcnew BitArray(encodedSource->ToArray());

            return bits;
        }

        String ^Decode(BitArray ^bits)
        {
            Node ^current = this->Root;
            String ^decoded = "";

            for each (bool bit in bits)
            {
                if (bit)
                {
                    if (current->Right != nullptr)
                    {
                        current = current->Right;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (current->Left != nullptr)
                    {
                        current = current->Left;
                    }
                }

                if (IsLeaf(current))
                {
                    decoded += current->Symbol;
                    current = this->Root;
                }
            }

            return decoded;
        }

        bool IsLeaf(Node ^node)
        {
            return (node->Left == nullptr && node->Right == nullptr);
        };
}
```

Помогите пожалуйста, исправить правильно...

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76160/discussion-on-question-by-----orderby--c-cli).

Answer (score 2):

[`OrderBy` — это метод расширения, который лежит в классе `Enumerable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966(v=vs.110).aspx), соответственно вместо `source.OrderBy(...)` всегда можно написать `Enumerable.OrderBy(source, ...)`. Переведите это на C++ и всё заработает.

Это же относится и к прочим методам расширения, таким как `ToList`, `Take`, `FirstOrDefault`, `ToArray` (это из того что я увидел в вашем фрагменте).

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь, `Enumerable::OrderBy`, т. к. статический метод. http://www.glennslayden.com/code/linq/using-linq-in-cpp-cli

Comment: Ну мой пример на C#, а для автора я написал: "Переведите это на C++ и всё заработает"